# Accessing multiple sheets in Excel via powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am importing data into excel via Powershell, it is performance stats for CPU memeory and disk.

I wish to have three sheets within excel and write data into each one, 
I cant understand how to select which sheet i am working with. Change the active sheet before writing the value 
I am inserting into the active sheet  with the code below however how do i change sheets

Thanks

example code is

```
$xl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application" 
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.Add()
$ws=$wb.ActiveSheet
$cells=$ws.Cells
$cells.item(1,1).font.bold=$True
$cells.item(1,1).font.size=18
$s1=$wb.sheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet1'}
$s1.name = "CPU_Stats"
$wb.Sheets.add()
$s2 = $wb.sheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet2'}
$s2.name = "Memory_Consumption"
$wb.Sheets.add()
$s3 = $wb.sheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet3'}
$s3.name = "System_Drive_Usage"
$wb.author = "Tim Chettle"
$wb.title = "Capacity Management "
$wb.subject = "Data set Imported from CSV Files" + $d
$sheetarray=$s1.Name , $s2.Name , $s3.Name 
#define some variables to control navigation
$row=3
$col=2
$cells.item($row,$col)="test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are calling `$wb.sheets.add()` unless your workbook does not have 3 worksheets already. As for selecting which worksheet is the active sheet... this probably would have told you:

```
$wb.sheets|gm
```

If you do that you'll notice a Method named `Select`, which is what you want to do. Honestly, you don't even need to select the sheet to make it active though if you reference it directly when you go to insert things into it.

If I were you I'd get the PowerShell Community Extensions ([PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)) if for no other reason than to get the `Out-Clipboard` command. Then you can do fun things like:

```
$DriveUsage | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInfo -Delimiter "`t" | Out-Clipboard
$PasteTarget = $s3.Range("A1","A1")
$s3.Paste($PasteTarget, $false)
```

That will paste the `$DriveUsage` object into the System_Drive_Usage worksheet, headers and all.

Answer (score 0):

You already define the "sheets" in a variable

```
$s1.name = "CPU_Stats"
$wb.Sheets.add()
$s2 = $wb.sheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet2'}
$s2.name = "Memory_Consumption"
$wb.Sheets.add()
$s3 = $wb.sheets | where {$_.name -eq 'Sheet3'}
$s3.name = "System_Drive_Usage"
```

In order to activate it. Call the variable with activate.

```
$s1.activate()
$s2.activate()
$s3.activate()
```